# HTACCESS not working with rewriteCond

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page where I set a cookie named "utm" which contains the IP of each user.

After that the user access another page and I want to check if the cookie "utm" is set and if the cookie's value is the IP of the user. It's very simple but I cannot make it to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*utm=([^;]*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^%1$
RewriteRule .* error.html [L]
```

The problem is that the user is always ejected to error.html even if the cookie's value is the IP. The most strange is that if I test it putting explicitly my IP it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*utm=([^;]*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.222.111.222$
RewriteRule .* error.html [L]
```

So, when I put my IP in the regexp I am not ejected to error.html and everything works fine but when I dont but my IP and use %1 instead it does not work even the cookie having exactly my IP and nothing less.

---

### EDIT

With the help of Mr. anubhava I came to the following code. But it still does not work when the IP contained in the cookie is different of the real user's IP:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/index\.php|/teste\.php|/)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*utm=([^;]*).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^.*utm=([^;]*).*:(?!\1)$
RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not working because `%1` on RHS of `RewriteCond` isn't allowed.

You can this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} utm=([^;]*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}::%{REMOTE_ADDR} utm=([^;]+).*?::(?!\1).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ error.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! You are very right! Just one final question: if I want to do this: if the cookie utm is not set eject to error.html OR if the cookie utm is set and the IP is not the content eject to error.html (this last if you already answered but is there any fancy way to join this 2 statements without using 2 rewriterule? I tried using OR but it does not work as expected!

Comment: I am on mobile at present, give me few minutes and I will update the answer as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: thanks @anubhava ! I edited my question so it can be easier to you to understand what I want and what I have so far! Thank you so much for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of anubhava I figured it out and fixed my problem! The code must be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/index\.php|/teste\.php|/)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*utm=([^;]*).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^.*utm=([^;]*).*:(?!\1).*$
RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
```